# WSO2 as a Orchestration Service or Apache Nifi as Orchestration Service

Tags: wso2, apache-nifi, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 and Apache Nifi. After having gone through official WSO2 and Apache Nifi documentation and some other sites, I am still having doubts regarding my use case and using WSO2 or Apache Nifi for that.

My use case is as follows

I have multiple REST APIs, each of which is a processing step in a multi-step processing. Some of the processing steps can take time in the magnitude of seconds (2 to 4s). In order to scale them, I want to run multiple instances of each processing steps (REST APIs) on same port but different VM.

In order to orchestrate call between these processing steps, What is more appropriate to use Apache Nifi or WSO2 ESB Service Orchestration.

Comment: nifi allows you to create dataflows. and wso2esb provides a way to create proxy services - the new services that will call other services.

Comment: Are there any options in WSO2 product suite for Service Orchestration (in particular for the use case I mentioned)

Comment: both products could call services sequentially. your case is not very descriptive to make a choice.nifi - if it's etl-like dataflow, or state machine flow. wso2esb - to publish new services that calls other existing services. wso2bps - is bpmn-based business process server that also could be considered as a service orchestrator.